# Animated GIF stops too soon after some frames in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, animated-gif

In **[this page with an animated GIF](https://www.energie-environnement.ch/dechets-recyclage/1430)**, if you put your mouse over the bullets containing a number, the image changes; this works correctly in all recent browsers, except Firefox (46, 47), where sometimes the replacing animated GIF blocks, stopped too soon.

It's a simple initial GIF `img` linked with a `map`. In this map, some `area` (the numbers) react with JavaScript on mouse over and switch the URL in the `src` attribute of the image. These replacing images are others animated GIF.
Here you can see an excerpt of the html :

```
<img src="/images/visites-dechets/uiom-kva/uiom-kva.gif" id="img_usine" alt="UIOM" width="1000" height="600" usemap="#uiom-kva" style="height: auto; max-width: 100%;" />
<map id="uiom-kva" name="uiom-kva"> 
<area shape="circle" alt="" coords="101,484,22" href="#" id="btn-anim-1" class="remplacer" />
...
<area shape="circle" alt="" coords="412,221,22" href="#" id="btn-anim-9" class="remplacer" />

</map>
```

The JavaScript is very simple, here is how it look likes :

```
...
jQuery(".remplacer").mouseover( function ()
{   
    ...
    jQuery("#img_usine").attr("src", newurl);
    ...
}
...
```

It seems to be a Firefox bug. Do you know if a workaround exists ?

Comment: Rather than changing the `src`, can you remove the GIF from the page, and insert a new one with the new `src` url? Not sure if that would help but its worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @romellem  I tried in [this version](http://www.energie-environnement.ch/component/content/article/132-fr-fr/la-maison/visites-dechets/1443?tmpl=component) to change `img` rather than `src` attribute. The problem disappear but now the switch blinks (in the first rollover) and sometimes a GIF animation doesn't restart at the begining.
I asked a question about the blink here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205083/how-to-avoid-a-blink-when-switching-2-gif-images-display

Comment: I think I saw the site while you were in the middle of updating it. Anyways, I don't think the `.fadeIn` `.fadeOut` works in this case, and you should be using just a plain `.hide` `.show`. For the record, I don't see a "blink" on the initial rollover. The reason for that blink would be because the browser hasn't loaded the new .gif file as soon as the old one is removed from the page. I'd think you'd need to preload those so the browser caches the animated gifs.

Comment: Yes I was doing some tests... and indeed, I'm not sure fading is a solution. It sounds really that the other images are not preload, because the blink happens only the first time, but the images are actually preloaded.